# Ruby on Rails - Automatically create objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, model-view-controller, methods

In my application I have `user` table, and an `activities` tables- the `user` has three types of `activities`. I also have a `weeks` table - every `activity` has a set number of `weeks` and the `user` owns those activities. So the `weeks` belong to the `users` and the `activities`, and the `activities` belong to the `users`. Below is my `users` table:

```
class SorceryCore < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :users do |t|
     t.string :first_name
     t.string :surname
     t.integer :previous_award
     t.integer :chosen_award
     t.string :email,            :null => false
     t.string :crypted_password
     t.string :salt

     t.timestamps
     end

   add_index :users, :email, unique: true
  end
end
```

Below is my activities table:

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
   create_table :activities do |t|
     t.integer :activity_type
     t.string :activity_name
     t.string :approver_email
     t.references :users, index: true, foreign_key: true

     t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
 end
```

Below is my weeks table:

```
class CreateWeeks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :weeks do |t|
      t.integer :week_num
      t.date :date_completed
      t.time :time_completed
      t.boolean :submitted
      t.boolean :approved
      t.references :activities, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :users, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The user registration process is a multi-stage sign up. When a user registers, they also create their 3 activities. I want to automatically create a number of week objects for each activity, with default values. This number of weeks created, should be equal to the input from the user registration process - the attribute from the users table called 'chosen award'. 
i.e. i want the number of weeks for activity 1 to equal:

```
current_user.chosen_award
```

Is there a way to automatically create these week objects for each activity that relate back to the current user, with default values?

UPDATE:
Week Model:

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :activities
   belongs_to :users
end
```

Activities Model:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy

    $activity_type_var = 1;

end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy
    authenticates_with_sorcery!
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 3 }
    validates :password, confirmation: true
    validates :email, uniqueness: true, email_format: { message: 'has invalid format' }

end
```

Comment: why you need `week` refers to `user` since `activity` refers to `user` and `week` refers `activity` already?

Comment: Maybe I don't? I thought I needed to create that relationship, but you're probably right, I don't think I need to include the user_id in the week table

Answer (score 0):

You can use Active Record Callback `after_create` on Activity model and create Week objects after creating Activity object.

If I understood your right, add to your Activity model:

```
after_create :create_weeks

def create_weeks
  user.chosen_award.times do
    weeks.create(user: user, week_num: 1) #add your default values
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord callbacks is a good option. I would also recommend you to rename :activity_type column to just :type. Then you can use single table inheritance out of the box and, if I understood you correctly, it's just what you need. [Here is a good guide about it](http://samurails.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/)